# sed replace text at based on line number dynamically

Tags: shell

I am looking for bash script comments from // to /*  */

I got partial working 
sed -i '14s/////*/' a.c 
this is working  like // with */  how to add */ at the end.

### Originl script

```
#include <stdio.h>


char buffer[10] = {'0'};  // comment1 

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World");  // Comment2 

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Expected file

```
#include <stdio.h>


char buffer[10] = {'0'};     /* comment1 */

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World"); /*  Comment2  */

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplest solution

Assuming the idiosyncratic spacing in the desired output shown in the question is unintentional:

```
sed 's%// *\(.*\)%/* \1 */%'
```

The keys here are:

1. Using `%` instead of `/` to mark the separate parts of the `s///` (or `s%%%`) command.
2. Capturing the text of the comment in `\(…\)`.
3. Replacing it with `\1` (preceded by `/*` and followed by `*/` and single spaces.

Working on a direct copy of the data from the question, the output is:

```
#include <stdio.h>


char buffer[10] = {'0'};  /* comment1  */

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World");  /* Comment2  */

    return 0;
}
```

#### Improving the handling of spaces

There are trailing blanks after the comments — ugly!  We can fix that with care:

```
sed 's%//[[:space:]]*\(.*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*$%/* \1 */%'
```

That matches zero or more spaces after the `//` opening the comment, and matches up to the last non-space before an optional string of spaces at the end of the line.  That generates:

```
#include <stdio.h>


char buffer[10] = {'0'};  /* comment1 */

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World");  /* Comment2 */

    return 0;
}
```

And you can deal with all trailing white space first, which is probably a good idea anyway, using:

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}$//' -e 's%//[[:space:]]*\(.*\)%/* \1 */%'
```

which yields:

```
#include <stdio.h>


char buffer[10] = {'0'};  /* comment1 */

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");  /* Comment2 */

    return 0;
}
```

That differs from the previous output by not having a space after `main()`.

#### Proper comment handling is hard!

Note that this simple code can easily be confused by valid C, such as:

```
printf("// this is not a comment\n");
```

To understand C fully enough not to make that mistake is beyond sensible `sed`.  Less seriously, it will miss some valid but implausible character sequences that are officially comments, such as:

```
/\
/this is a comment\
and this is also part of the comment\
    even    with    extra    spaces
```

and if you allow trigraphs (don't), then:

```
/??/
/??/
This is part of the comment started two lines before!
```

This sort of stuff shouldn't afflict any actual code base, but are the sorts of garbage that compiler writers have to handle correctly.

Comment: How to handle below type of comments
//      Package   : Test Application
//      File name : abcd_Main.c  // test text